# split not working for second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unable to split same string for two times.What i am doing wrong?

```
        // my original string
        var str = "Left,Right-broken at left side";     
        var ary = "Left,Right-broken at left side";

        //getting text after - (working fine)
        var res = str.split("-").pop();
        $('#disc_comm_tlside_ed').empty();
        $('#disc_comm_tlside_ed').val(res);

        // with this i can get text before -once again i need to splt by comma only
        var myarrays= str.substr(0, str.indexOf('-'));

        //even this also returning original string 
        var splt = ary.split(',');

        // alert(splt)  when i alert this getting full string
        for(var i = 0; i < splt.length; i++)
        {
            //alert(myarray[i]);
            $(this).find("option[value ='"+myarray[i]+"']").attr("selected",true);
            $('.batch_ed').multiselect('rebuild');
        }
```

Finally returning original string!!

Need to get text before-and split text separated by ,

need to get left and right only as array

Edit: adding the code snippet posted in the comment.

```
 var elements = ""; 
            var batchnoe= ""; 
            $.each(data.response.frc_disloc, function (a,b){ 
              batchnoe = '.batch_ed'; 
              $(batchnoe).each(function(i, obj) { 
                var batch_splt = b.frac_side; 
                var myarray = batch_splt.split(','); 
                for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) { 
                  $(this).find("option[value ='"+myarray[i]+"']").attr("selected",true); $('.batch_ed').multiselect('rebuild'); 
                } 
              }); 
             });
```

Comment: *"alert(splt)  when i alert this getting full string"* – of course you do, because `alert()` converts the array back to a string. Don't use `alert` for debugging. Open the browser console and use `console.log()`.

Comment: Can you separate code from question text?  The "code" here is essentially garbage.

Comment: Can you show what your real JavaScript looks like, without the comments in between? The things that look like comments would cause syntax errors, so I just want to make sure.

Comment: @david it keep on asking me to add some text in the question

Comment: Yes, *in the question*, not in your code.

Comment: @satishkilari: That's because your question is light on text.  If you separate code and text into their own things and elaborate on the problem, it'll be fine.  If you just dump random keystrokes into the question, the quality filter might complain about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check console logs for the output.

```js
         // my original string
                var str = "Left,Right-broken at left side";     
                var ary = "Left,Right-broken at left side";

                //getting text after - (working fine)
                var res = str.split("-").pop();
       
                $('#disc_comm_tlside_ed').empty();
                $('#disc_comm_tlside_ed').val(res);

                // with this i can get text before -once again i need to splt by comma only
                var myarrays= str.substr(0, str.indexOf('-'));
        
                //even this also returning original string 
                var splt = myarrays.split(',');
                console.log(splt);
                // alert(splt)  when i alert this getting full string
                for(var i = 0; i < splt.length; i++)
                {
                    console.log(splt[i]);
                    $(this).find("option[value ='"+splt[i]+"']").attr("selected",true);
                    //$('.batch_ed').multiselect('rebuild');
                }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="disc_comm_tlside_ed"></div>
```

Comment: var elements = "";
var batchnoe= "";  
$.each(data.response.frc_disloc, function (a,b){
batchnoe = '.batch_ed';
$(batchnoe).each(function(i, obj) {
var batch_splt = b.frac_side;
var myarray = batch_splt.split(',');
for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
{
$(this).find("option[value ='"+myarray[i]+"']").attr("selected",true);
$('.batch_ed').multiselect('rebuild');
}
});
});

Comment: @satishkilari I hope the answer helped.

Comment: no not much,thanks for your time please see above script in comments.as same i did still no luck

Comment: I see you are looping through this data.response.frc_dislo can you please post this data as well.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [frac_disloc_id] => 1
            [consult_id] => 18
            [frac_side] => Left,Right-broken at left side
            [loc_frac] => Middle,Distal-knee
            [type_frac] => Closed,Open-big hole
            
     
        )

)

Comment: @satishkilari  I have done a correction in the answer do check again. but the posted data i am not able to understand json format would have helped a lot.